# Oracle SQL user defined hints

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

Does oracle allow creation of mnemonics for hints in SQL? I am not able to find any such concept in Oracle docs but I have found certain queries running in production with hints like the below one:

```
select /*+ AHintWhichIsNotInOracleDocumentation */ from some_table;
```

I thought optimizer would safely ignore this until I found http://www.confio.com/logicalread/oracle-11g-making-query-run-magically-faster-mc02/#.U_D8WqOTJUA

The author talks about "adding" a hint called "RICHS_SECRET_HINT" in the "X$" tables? Is this feature available in Oracle? If yes, links to docs please. Thanks.

Edit:
To clarify further, I am looking to find if there Oracle provides ways to create a key-value sort of relationship between new hints and Oracle provided hints. This seems to be a pointless feature considering it is good only to shorten the length of the hints when there are a lot of hints used in a SQL which is rarely the case. But considering the hints I saw in work, I am more curious to find if they exists or not.

So in essence in the above SQL, I am expecting some mapping between `AHintWhichIsNotInOracleDocumentation` and Oracle's standard hints like `ORDERED`, `USE_NL`, etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you've linked to has nothing to do with creating your own hint.  The article is demonstrating that it is relatively easy to trick yourself into thinking that you have improved the performance of a query (in this case by adding a hint that does nothing) when the reality is that the performance improved only because data has been cached by the prior executions.

You cannot define your own hints.  There are hints that are undocumented.  Given how rarely using a documented hint is the proper long-term answer to improving query performance (it almost always makes sense to fix the underlying statistics issue or to create a profile/ outline/ etc.), it would be exceedingly unlikely that you'd want to use an undocumented hint.  I can't imagine a case where it would make sense to be able to define your own hint.